# Django dashboard performance

Tags: django

I've designed a dashboard using Django and it has following elements:
1. User task
2. User email/notifications
3. 5 cards, representing summaries
4. 1 Pie-Chart
5. 1 Progress bar chart

It's my local development and I don't have much data in system, so all loads within a second. I use custom SQL queries (RawSQL) to build my dataset; because I want to hide my Models being accessed directly and also there is complex joins involved for fetching results.

I doubt this design may not be scalable with Production data. Please advice me to build my dataset as smaller sets and secure. I've already considered the Ajax; however, need experts advice or any reference to design scalable QuerySet/execution of those.

Comment: if the dashboard doesn't have to dynamic, you can create charts in the backend using something like `matplotlib` and load it in the front end.

Comment: you can use `mongodb` to store dashboard data. it will be faster and scalable.